# How should I set threshold parameter in find_eog_events() function?

Tags: python

I am working with [DEAP dataset](https://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/mmv/datasets/deap/) and [MNE](https://mne.tools/stable/index.html).

I need to find eye-blinks using [find_eog_events()](https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.preprocessing.find_eog_events.html#mne.preprocessing.find_eog_events) function. As you can see in the documentation, I am supposed to specify a parameter called `thresh`:

> Threshold to trigger the detection of an EOG event. This controls the thresholding of the underlying peak-finding algorithm. Larger values mean that fewer peaks (i.e., fewer EOG events) will be detected. If None, use the default of (max(eog) - min(eog)) / 4, with eog being the filtered EOG signal.

I tried to use the default value (i.e., `(max(eog)-min(eog))/4`) but unfortunately many non-blinks artifacts are detected (wrongly).

Can you give me an advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on the same dataset some days ago.

You can try:

1. use the same data lenght of the video trials (1 minute for trial)
2. using vertical EOGs or Fp1 and Fp2 of EEGs data
3. using as thresh: (max(data_filtered) - min(data_filtered))/2.
   data_filtered to band pass 1 - 10 hz

Bye

Comment: Why are you diving by 2?

Comment: is a magic number that seems to work well

Comment: Have you observed it working fine for each subject in the dataset?

Comment: should work well if there is at least one blink in the trial, because when calculating the max and min there is a substantial difference with the basic signal (without blink)

Comment: How do I handle the cases when a subject does not blink?

Comment: it's very simple.. come on